# Did men sell their wives on Wednesbury market?

Tags: history, marriage

To my knowledge wife sales on Wednesbury market were a bit of a family legend my great-grandfather used to tell. However, it seems to be more widely spread than that. I have found [an article](http://www.peterleeson.com/Wife_Sales.pdf) which tries to explain the reasons for wife sales and indeed indicates that they were conducted on Wednesbury market?

Is this a spoof article (it doesn't seem to be from an academic journal)? Are wife sales (and in particular wife sales on Wednesbruy market) a myth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not a myth, no.

> *Wife selling in England was a way of ending an unsatisfactory marriage
>   by mutual agreement that probably began in the late 17th century, when
>   divorce was a practical impossibility for all but the very wealthiest.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wife_selling_(English_custom) -(I know, wikipedia isn't 100%)

It was simply due to women had no real rights when married, and marriage wasn't registered, so men could just "pass on" the woman and the marriage.

Another source that list a series of claimed evens of such sales: http://www.ontalink.com/history/18th_century/regions/British/wife_selling.html

> **Dated 1720 from an old magazine known as "Lloyd's,"**
>
> *We were lately
>   witnesses of a case of wife-selling in an old town in South
>   Staffordshire. It appeared that the husband had set his affections on
>   another woman, and his wife hearing of it, had very justly showed
>   their displeasure in a variety of ways; whereupon the husband, who was
>   a collier, took her to the marketplace, and sold her to the highest
>   bidder for five shillings. There was much excitement in the crowd
>   which assembled to witness the act, and the affair ended with a good
>   deal of drinking at the expense of the husband and the purchaser."*

While no clear indication of sales happening in Wednesbury market, the fact it was supposedly a marked during the time these wife sales are said to happen, indicates it is quite possible. While I can't find exact moment of when the area became an actual market, there is a reference to a time indicating things started to happen:

> *In 1315, coal pits were first recorded, which led to an increase in
>   the number of jobs. Nail making was also in progress during these
>   times.*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wednesbury

Comment: In 1720 Wednesbury was an small old town in south Staffordshire. Boundaries have moved since then, and it is more populated now.